# Repeated match inside match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

```
   $regex = '/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is';

   $string = '[b][b][b]string[/b][/b][/b]';
```

This will only match until the first [/b], so if I use this regex to convert this bbcode to HTML I will end up with this:

```
string[/b][/b]
```

I'm using PHP preg_replace, how I can end up with just `string`, so 3 html bold tags.

Comment: Maybe `\[(\/?)b\]` with `<$1strong>` this doesn't check for matched pairings though.. This would be the same as `str_replace(array('[b]','[/b]'), array('<strong>', '</strong>')`

Comment: Can't you do asymmetric replacement (`\[(\/|)b\]` to `<$1b>`)?

Comment: You can repeatedly replace until nothing else is matched.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/15qAsY. You may run `$re = '~\[b]((?:(?!\[/?b]).)*)\[/b]~is';` in a loop until no match.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew that's useful too, maybe I can use **revo** solution to parse the user input since it removes unnecessary tags, and this that looks more simple to convert all pairing tags to HTML.

Comment: @Vixxs Regex can't handle generic nesting properly, it's not able to do so. Please use my Shortcode library with either Regex or Regular parser to do so: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such dirty cases:

```
this [b]is [b]a[/b][/b] test [b]string[/b]
```

A recursive solution works:

```
\[b](?:(?:(?!\[b]).)*?|(?R))*\[/b]
```

[Live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/6GcAnH/1)

PHP code:

```
$str = 'this [b]is [b]a[/b][/b] test [b]string[/b]';

echo preg_replace_callback('~\[(\w+)](?:(?:(?!\[\1]).)*?|(?R))*\[/(\1)]~', function($m) {
    return "**".preg_replace("~\[/?$m[1]]~", '', $m[0])."**";
}, $str);
```

Outputs:

```
this **is a** test **string**
```

Comment: In Live Demo at regex101 , if you click on pcre flavor, it will show 'pattern error' because of last slash. can be fixed by backslash. thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you didn't look at provided live demo in my answer carefully. (It's on PCRE flavor already) @MohaMad

Comment: I know, it's regex101 bug! try clicking on pcre or change it to javascript and back to pcre, please @revo

Comment: It's not a bug. Regex delimiter simply backs to default (`/`) when you re-select PCRE flavor which right now is `@`.

Comment: I never change delimiter and never check it, thanks @revo

Comment: I mean that's my bad that didn't pay attention to delimiters, and you're right, there is no bug in regex. and I say again, thanks for your comments :) @revo

Answer (score 1):

You can use a non-capture group to extend the repetition count:

```
(?:\[b\])+(.*?)(?:\[\/b\])+
^^^     ^^     ^^^       ^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3AG8fB/1)

Comment: Is there a way that could it work with strings like this: [b][b][b]string[/b]string[/b]string[/b]

Comment: @revo I'm not sure BBCode could provide such collisions, does it?

Comment: @Vixxs what result do you except for such an input?

Comment: **stringstringstring** perhaps it's imposible.

Comment: @Vixxs you want to remove `[b]` or replace with `*`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does.